# How can I see what fonts support a given character?

Tags: fonts

Say I’m looking for a list of which of my installed fonts support a given Unicode character. say the ⁂ and ☺ characters (an asterism and emoticon smile). What graphical program would I use to preview this characters in the given font?

Comment: @ThomasDickey That assumes that the font file is known and what is searched for is: which characters it has?. Here, the reverse question is asked. Given an UNICODE code point, Which fonts support it?

Comment: There is no program (AFAIK) to list the fonts that carry a given glyph (UNICODE code point image, colloquially called character). However in Gnome there is `charmap` and in kde there is `KCharSelect`. Both are similar and work quite well. I'll recommend that you install CODE2000 with over 60000 glyphs (no, not CODE2001 or other, they are worse) search in wikipedia for the name, the download link is at the bottom.

Comment: Also, as a fallback for very uncommon glyphs [install unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html) it has 100% coverage of the BMP and many glyphs elsewhere. The only caveat is that it is a raster font (not so good quality) but serves as fall back for almost anything (Linux does the fallback automatically).

Comment: As pointed out by @BinaryZebra, I’m interested in the the fonts that support a given character.